# call Slider by function fltk c++

Tags: c++, fltk

I hope there is someone who could give me a hint with the following. I´m almost done with a algorithm in quantum mechanics which I programmed in fltk C++. The algorithm describes the spreading of an Gaussian curve. The last step I did is to create at the top on my widget 3 sliders. The first one describes the "time", second one is the "Wave packet with sigma" and the last one is the "Momentum (mu)". Now I need to connect my formula `psi[i]` under "double PsiGau"-function with the three sliders. I need to play with the sliders and change my graph. Does anyone have a idea?

Here is my code:

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Get the fltk distribution package.  Under test, there are two programs.

- arc.cxx
- curve.cxx

Have a look at them - they are similar to what you want.

**Edit**

Download fltk from http://www.fltk.org/software.php  Get the 1.3.4 package.  Unzip it, go to the test directory and have a look at curve.cxx

Comment: Sorry, but do not know what u meaning. Unfortunaty, I coudn´t post my code here because, it was refused. But I could send it to someone if you´re pass me the email

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include<FL/Fl_Int_Input.H>
#include<FL/Fl_slider.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Menu_Bar.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include<FL/Fl_Menu_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/fl_draw.H>
#include <math.h>
#include<complex>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

#include<stdio.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include<FL/Fl_Int_Input.H>
#include<FL/Fl_slider.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Menu_Bar.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include<FL/Fl_Menu_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

Comment: #include <math.h>
#include<complex>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

#define M_PI 3.141592671
const complex<double> I(0.0,1.0);
static  double Xmin=-5,Xmax= 10;//x range
//specify potential range:
static int L=3;
static double hbar =1.0;
const int Nmax = 1024;
const int PicWidth = 512;
static int tracePos = 0;
static int psiPos = 0;
static int PicBreak = 0;
static float PSItr[Nmax];
static float psi_view[PicWidth];

const double SIGmax =5.;
const double SIGmin =1.4,mu=.0002;//(Momentum)

Comment: class SliderIn : public Fl_Group {

 Fl_Int_Input *input;
    Fl_Slider *slider;

public:


 void sliderI()
 {
  static int recurse=0;

  if(recurse){ return;}

  else
  {
   recurse=1;
   char S[150];
   sprintf(S,"%d",(int)(slider->value() +mu));

   input->value(S);
   recurse=0;
  }
 }

 static void sliderI(Fl_Widget *w,void *data)
 {
  ((SliderIn*)data)->sliderI();

Comment: complex<double>psi[Nmax]; double sig;
 }

  SliderIn(int x, int y, int w, int h,const char *L=0):Fl_Group(x,y,w,h,L){

     int in_w = 40;
        input  = new Fl_Int_Input(x, y, in_w, h);
        input->callback(sliderI, (void*)this);
        input->when(FL_WHEN_ENTER_KEY|FL_WHEN_NOT_CHANGED);

        slider = new Fl_Slider(x+in_w, y, w-in_w, h);
        slider->type(1);
        slider->callback(sliderI, (void*)this);

        bounds(1, 60);     // some usable default
        value(0);          // some usable default
        end();             // close the group   
   }

Comment: int value() const { return (int)slider->value()/*+3*/; }
  void value(int val){ slider->value(val);sliderI();}

  void mini(int val){slider->minimum();}
  int mini() const {return ((int)slider->minimum());}

  void maxi(int val){slider->maximum();}
  int maxi() const {return ((int)slider->maximum());}
  void bounds(double low,int high) { slider->bounds(1,60);}
 
};

Comment: class CN_act:  public Fl_Box
{
 void draw();

public:
 

 CN_act(int x, int y,int w,int h, const char *l=0) : Fl_Box (x,y,w,h,l) {}
 
   double V(double x);
   double H(double x);
    
 void C_NickolsTridiagonalmat(double psi[Nmax],double Ham[Nmax]);
 double PsiGau(complex<double> psi[Nmax], double mu,double sig);

};

       /******************
  * if t=0, we get A
  * if t=1, we get B
  * if t=20,we have 20% of way from A to B(Ax to Bx etc..)
  *******************/
  

void ticks(int Ax,int Ay,int Bx,int By)
{ 

 //5 ticks, in k equal parts
 double k=6.;

Comment: @Edd edit your original post and paste the code there instead of in comments